# wxPython - How to change ListCtrl Item index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to change the Index of a ListCtrl item by the state of its checkbox. To get the state of the checkbox isnt that hard, but i cant find a way to change the index of the checked item.

My code looks like this:

```
class FilterCheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT | 
                wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.SetSize(-1, -1, -1, 50)

    def OnCheckItem(self, index, flag):        
        item = self.GetItem(index)
        
        if flag: 
            item.SetId(0)
            self.Update()
```

As an addition i would also like to sort it back into the list (alphabetical order) when not checked. Is there a good way to do this?

P.S. i know that the checkbox behaviour was changed in the latest version of wxPython, but i need to stay on the older version due to some problems with Matplotlib and wxPython 4.1.1!

Comment: try to get it's info, then delete it and insert a new one in a different place

Comment: As @LeonardoScotti points out replacement is easier than trying to mess around. Sorting is the same, it's often easier to `listCtrl.DeleteAllItems()` and then repopulate according to your chosen criteria. That does of course suppose, that you have a list or a database query to access the data quickly.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony When i insert the item again, i need to check the checkbox as well. This is causing the OnCheckItem to fire again. Is there a way to check an item without that in wxPython 4.0 ?

Comment: You could always set a flag to ignore the event during the reload process.

Comment: I know how to do this with Events but OnCheckItem isnt really bound to an event it just fires. I know there is something behind that, but as always hard to find the correct documentation without the right words :-D could you help me out one last time (hopefully :D)

Comment: `EVT_LIST_ITEM_CHECKED` I assume. Note: `wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.CheckListCtrlMixin` This class is obsolete as wx.ListCtrl now includes nearly the same functionality.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! Then i got you correct. But i cant switch to the new wxPython version due a Bug with Matplotlib.